# date picker showing error

Tags: android, eclipse, datepicker

I'm trying to add a Date Picker to my code, but an error is being shown over "pickerListener" inside the "fromDate_textView.setOnClickListener" saying:

> pickerListener cannot be resolved to a variable

Can anyone please help me solve the issue?

```
fromDate_textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            showDialog(DatePickerDialog(Sell_Product_Activity.this,
                    pickerListener, year, month, day));
        }
    });

    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {

            year = selectedYear;
            month = selectedMonth;
            day = selectedDay;

            // Show selected date
            fromDate_textView.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
                    .append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year)
                    .append(" "));

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this Code may solve your Problem, Its working fine

```
  // for date picker

        private int year;
        private int month;
        private int day;
        static final int DATE_PICKER_ID = 1111;

// for date picker
    private EditText m3_DateDisplay;

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

m3_DateDisplay = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);


         // Get current date by calender

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Show current date

        /*m3_DateDisplay.setText(new StringBuilder()
                // Month is 0 based, just add 1
                .append(day).append("-").append(month + 1).append("-")
                .append(year).append(" "));*/


        // Show selected date
        StringBuilder dateValue1=new StringBuilder().append(day).append("-")
        .append(month + 1).append("-").append(year).append(" ");


        //for Converting Correct Date format Save into Database
        SimpleDateFormat sdf123 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        String abs1= dateValue1.toString();
        Date testDate1 = null;
         try {
            testDate1 = sdf123.parse(abs1);
        } catch (ParseException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SimpleDateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        String DateFormat=formatter1.format(testDate1);

        m3_DateDisplay.setText(DateFormat);



            m3_DateDisplay.setFocusable(false);
            m3_DateDisplay.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
            m3_DateDisplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    showDialog(DATE_PICKER_ID);
                }
            });

    }

    @Override
        protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
        {
            switch (id) {
            case DATE_PICKER_ID:

                // open datepicker dialog.
                // set date picker for current date
                // add pickerListener listner to date picker
                //return new DatePickerDialog(this, pickerListener, year, month, day);

                /////Only Show till Date Not More than That.
                    DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, pickerListener, year, month, day);
                    dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());
                    return dialog;
            }
            return null;
        }

        private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
        {

            // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                    int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {

                year = selectedYear;
                month = selectedMonth;
                day = selectedDay;



                // Show selected date
                            StringBuilder dateValue=new StringBuilder().append(day).append("-")
                            .append(month + 1).append("-").append(year).append(" ");


                //for Converting Correct Date format Save into Database
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf123 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                            String abs1= dateValue.toString();
                            Date testDate1 = null;
                             try {
                                testDate1 = sdf123.parse(abs1);
                            } catch (ParseException e) {

                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                SimpleDateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                            String DateFormat=formatter1.format(testDate1);

                            m3_DateDisplay.setText(DateFormat);


            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare pickerListener before setting the OnClickListener and make pickerListener final so that it can be accessed inside the OnClickListener. This should work:

```
final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
            int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {

        year = selectedYear;
        month = selectedMonth;
        day = selectedDay;

        // Show selected date
        fromDate_textView.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
                .append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year)
                .append(" "));

    }
};

fromDate_textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog= new DatePickerDialog(Sell_Product_Activity.this,
        pickerListener, year, month, day);
        datePickerDialog.show();
    }
});
```

**EDIT:**
I combined my first answer with Sanjeet Ajnabee's answer. I hope it works for you! It made no problems when I tested it.

Comment: On doing as you said, there is error in "DatePickerDialog" inside the onClickListener, mentioning "The method DatePickerDialog(Sell_Product_Activity, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener, int, int, int) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}".

Comment: did you write Sell_Product_Activity instead of Sell_Product_Activity.this?

Answer (score 0):

Modify the code-

```
fromDate_textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            showDialog(DatePickerDialog(Sell_Product_Activity.this,
                    pickerListener, year, month, day));
        }
    });
```

AS-

```
fromDate_textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog= new DatePickerDialog(this,
            pickerListener, year, month, day);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Again I'm facing the same error "pickerListener cannot be resolved to a variable".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. The problem is actually with "Monkey Talk" library which I used in project. Once after removing this lib, date picker started working fine