# Is there any possibility to do the scroll view same as date picker scroll view in android?

Tags: android, uiscrollview

I have tried scroll view same as date picker, but failed.

I have done through this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="clip_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical">
       <TextView
                android:text="Movies"
                android:id="@+id/text01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>     
        -
        -
        -
        -           
    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**My output:**

[image]

I want to pick some one of this scroll view select list in my example, how can I do this same as date picker.

**Expected Output:**

[image]

Comment: Try this , It may Help you like Scroll date picker

[Link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30455168/4447803