# Error in Android Edittext Onclick Datepickerdialog in lollipop

Tags: java, android, datepickerdialog

I am using datepickerdialog. it run properly on kitkat but when i run application on lollipop and when i click on edit text it opens a datepickerdialog box but when i select date it give unfortunately stop error. Below is the code for datepicker on edittext.

```
private void setDateTimeField() {
                     fromLabel.setOnClickListener(this);
                     toLabel.setOnClickListener(this);



                     final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");  //yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss
                    final Date date = new Date();
                    final String u = dateFormat.format(date);


                     Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                     fromDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new OnDateSetListener() {

                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                             Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();

                             newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                             from1 = dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime());
                             diff1 = newDate.getTimeInMillis();
                             long d = date.getTime();


                             if((newDate.getTime()).equals(date)||(newDate.getTime()).after(date)){
                                 long d1 = (diff1 / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) - d / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) + 1;
                                   if(d1>30){ 
                                         total.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                         total.setText("Booking not allowed as the Date given is outside Advance Booking Period");
                                         avail.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                     }
                                   else{
                                         total.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                         fromLabel.setText(from1);
                                         toLabel.setText(null);
                                         to=null;
                                         avail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                         from=fromLabel.getText().toString();
                                   }
                             }
                             else{
                                 total.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                 total.setText("Choose date after or equals to current date");
                                 fromLabel.setText("");
                                 toLabel.setText(null);     
                                 from=null;     
                                 to=null;
                             }


                         }

                     },newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));



                     fromDatePickerDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, getString(R.string.Done), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                           if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE) {
                               dialog.cancel();
                               if(type.equals("According to time"))
                               {

                                  int cnt=-1;
                                 if(from1.equals(u)){
                                     cnt = 1;
                                     loadTimeSpinnerDataATT(text,from,cnt);
                                  }
                                  else if(total.getText()=="Choose date after or equals to current date")
                                  {

                                  }
                                  else if(total.getText()=="Booking not allowed as the Date given is outside Advance Booking Period")
                                  {

                                  }
                                 else
                                 {cnt = 0;

                                  loadTimeSpinnerDataATT(text,from,cnt);
                                 }

                               }
                           }
                        }
                      });

                 }


                 public void onClick(View view) {
                     if(view == fromLabel) {
                         fromDatePickerDialog.show();
                     } else if(view == toLabel) {
                         toDatePickerDialog.show();

                     }        
                 }


                 public void onClose(DialogInterface dialogInterface)
                 {

                 }
          }
```

Comment: When you get Unfortunately Stop Error, then you will be getting an exception. Check it out in Logcat and find out the reason or paste the exception stacktrace here so that we could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it, may help you,

Date picker error resloved here

[Link For Date picker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30455168/4447803)

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;
    static final int DATE_PICKER_ID = 1111;

    // for date picker
     EditText m3_DateDisplay;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        m3_DateDisplay = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.datepick);

        // Get current date by calender

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);




        // Show selected date
        StringBuilder dateValue1 = new StringBuilder().append(day).append("-")
                .append(month + 1).append("-").append(year).append(" ");

        // for Converting Correct Date format Save into Database
        SimpleDateFormat sdf123 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        String abs1 = dateValue1.toString();
        Date testDate1 = null;
        try {
            testDate1 = sdf123.parse(abs1);
        } catch (ParseException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SimpleDateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        String DateFormat = formatter1.format(testDate1);

        m3_DateDisplay.setText(DateFormat);

        m3_DateDisplay.setFocusable(false);
        m3_DateDisplay.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        m3_DateDisplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(DATE_PICKER_ID);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_PICKER_ID:

            // open datepicker dialog.
            // set date picker for current date
            // add pickerListener listner to date picker
            // return new DatePickerDialog(this, pickerListener, year, month,
            // day);

            // ///Only Show till Date Not More than That.
            DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                    pickerListener, year, month, day);
            dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());
            return dialog;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {

            year = selectedYear;
            month = selectedMonth;
            day = selectedDay;

            // Show selected date
            StringBuilder dateValue = new StringBuilder().append(day)
                    .append("-").append(month + 1).append("-").append(year)
                    .append(" ");

            // for Converting Correct Date format Save into Database
            SimpleDateFormat sdf123 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            String abs1 = dateValue.toString();
            Date testDate1 = null;
            try {
                testDate1 = sdf123.parse(abs1);
            } catch (ParseException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            SimpleDateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            String DateFormat = formatter1.format(testDate1);

            m3_DateDisplay.setText(DateFormat);

        }
    };
}
```

change minimum api-11 in manifest

Comment: @Mano I try this code but it give nullpointerexception on below line

'm3_DateDisplay.setText(DateFormat);'

Comment: n will you pls tell me that why my code is not working on lolipop n other? because it is working fine on kitkat

Comment: i missed the xml file  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: tested in lollipop. add this code in your project it will work try

Comment: it may help to solve your issue,just accept the answer :)

Comment: @Mano Thanks it is woking now :)