# how to disable certain specific dates in Android datepicker?

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite, datepicker

I have a datepicker which disables past dates. For my application, for example, user must be able to select only particular dates. The other dates must be disabled for selection. I do not want to validate after selection.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30844534/4447803 try lik this

Comment: This is a good question. Apparently it is not possible, might be worth adding for a future release.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, the best we could do is set Max and Min date for the date picker...
Or maybe you could create your own custom date picker to enable this.(Using NumberPicker for example)